# gazebo 1.6.7 in ros fuerte problems

Tags: ros-fuerte

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hello,

I'm working on ros fuerte with gazebo, yesterday i installed the version of simultaor gazebo 1.6.7 because i need to work with the contact sensors of the shadow_hand and the version that i have (1.6.16) has a problem with the contact_sensors, the installation was ok, but when i open my gazebo y too slow, then i try to run it in headless mode but it doesn't open it remains freeze.

When i run the gazebo normally i try to spawn the shadow hand but it doesn't appear, i don't know what is happening, someone knows what is wrong???

Runing in headless mode:

```
jose@ubuntu:~$ roslaunch gazebo_worlds empty_world_no_x.launch
... logging to /home/jose/.ros/log/62c8e30c-3ada-11e2-b606-e0ca942b6aa6/roslaunch-ubuntu-6429.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:45729/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro
 * /rosversion
 * /use_sim_time

NODES
  /
    gazebo (gazebo/gazebo)

auto-starting new master
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[master]: started with pid [6445]
ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

setting /run_id to 62c8e30c-3ada-11e2-b606-e0ca942b6aa6
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[rosout-1]: started with pid [6458]
started core service [/rosout]
Exception AttributeError: AttributeError("'_DummyThread' object has no attribute '_Thread__block'",) in <module 'threading' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.pyc'> ignored
process[gazebo-2]: started with pid [6472]
Gazebo multi-robot simulator, version 1.3.0
Copyright (C) 2012 Nate Koenig, John Hsu, and contributors.
Released under the Apache 2 License.
http://gazebosim.org

Warning [parser.cc:362] Converting a deprecatd SDF source[/home/jose/fuerte_workspace/simulator_gazebo/gazebo_worlds/worlds/empty.world].
Set SDF value
  Version[1.2] to Version[1.3]
  Please use the gzsdf tool to update your SDF files.
    $ gzsdf convert [sdf_file]
[ INFO] [1354272041.822041146]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
Msg Waiting for master
Msg Connected to gazebo master @ http://localhost:11345
[ INFO] [1354272043.627426014, 0.001000000]: joint trajectory plugin missing <updateRate>, defaults to 0.0 (as fast as possible)
[ INFO] [1354272043.659119580, 0.024000000]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1354272043.728475086, 0.090000000]: Starting to spin physics dynamic reconfigure node...
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/324/gazebo-1.6.7-in-ros-fuerte-problems/) by [joseescobar60](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/105/joseescobar60/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 36 on 2012-11-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Gazebo is a stand-alone package. Please do not use the version of Gazebo that ships with ROS. The version within ROS is old and unsupported.

[http://gazebosim.org/wiki/install](http://gazebosim.org/wiki/Install) describes how to install Gazebo.

Do not follow any of the Gazebo tutorials on the ROS website. They are old and unmaintained. Only use the tutorials on http://gazebosim.org/wiki

You can still use ROS Fuerte, but you should install Gazebo from the repository hosted by OSRF.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joseescobar60](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/105/joseescobar60/) on 2013-01-29**:
hey, i went out for a long time, i just read your anser and i installed the gazebo like you said to me, it works but the problem is when i need to work with ros and gazebo the tow applications are not bound, it works like a independient applications... any idea?

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-01-29**:
Can you explain your problem in more detail? Gazebo has always been a stand alone application (not tied to ROS).

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25/jbohren/) on 2013-03-13**:
Is @hsu just committing to the simulator_gazebo stack for kicks? https://code.ros.org/trac/ros-pkg/changeset/40366

**Comment by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) on 2013-03-13**:
@jbohren well, it is fun, you should try it sometimes  :)  trying to spin up another groovy release with gazebo 1.5.  turns out some of these test worlds might end up as gazebo unit tests directly in gazebo.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/25/jbohren/) on 2013-03-13**:
@hsu (: I might if I still had commit access to ros-pkg. I was actually going to create a branch to add something a couple months ago. Any thoughts on migrating that to git/hg/github/bitbucket?